# Not able to fetch Facebook friend photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I not able to get user friends photos not profile picture. I can easily get profile picture
but not able to get user friend photos 
I wrote this code but it is not working for me

```
 FB.api('me/friends?fields=albums', function(response) {
   for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++) {
      var album = response.data[i];
      FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos', function(photos){
        if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length){
        for (var j=0; j<photos.data.length; j++){
            var photo = photos.data[j];
            // photo.picture contain the link to picture
                var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = photo.picture;
            document.body.appendChild(image);
        }
    }
   });
  }
});
```

Given all the required permission friends_photos,publish_stream
But still no luck .
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your graph url is off. To get a specific users photo album list you need:

```
{user_id}/albums?fields={list_of_album_fields}
```

In conjunction with

```
user_photos and/or friends_photos permissions
```

The [Facebook graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is an excellent tool for getting your graph url's right before coding. Try it out to verify this solution.

If you're looking to get all albums for all friends in a single pass you'll need to formulate this as either [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/) or a [batch request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).